# detection idiom: why does the condition have to be a `using` directive?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

EDIT: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44044267/why-is-this-short-snippet-of-template-code-valid) other question of mine focuses on a reduced version of this problem, possibly easier to understand.

I wrote a small snippet that reproduces the behaviour of `std::experimental::is_detected` ([here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected)). My implementation is basically taken from cppreference but I got rid of the `Default` template parameter.

My question is: in the following snippet, why does `has_type` (the condition to be checked) *have* to be a `using` declaration and cannot be, e.g. a struct (in which case `is_detected` returns a wrong result)?

```
/***** is_detected definition *****/
template<typename...Args>
using void_t = void;

template<typename Void, template<class...> class Op, typename ...Args>
struct Detector {
   static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template<template<class ...> class Op, typename ...Args>
struct Detector<void_t<Op<Args...>>, Op, Args...> {
   static constexpr bool value = true;
};

template<template<class...> class Op, typename...Args>
using is_detected_t = Detector<void, Op, Args...>;
/****************************/

/***** is_detected test *****/
// two dummy types on which to test a condition
struct Yes { using type = void; };
struct No { };

// the condition to test
template<typename T>
using has_type = typename T::type;
// struct has_type { using type = typename T::type; }; // does not work as intended!

int main() {
   static_assert(is_detected_t<has_type, Yes>::value, "");
   static_assert(!is_detected_t<has_type, No>::value, "");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you wanted a struct, you'd have to use `has_type::type` instead of just `has_type` to make it work.

Comment: not sure I understand...`is_detected_t<has_type::type, No>::value` would not be a valid expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help to look at how `has_type` is actually used by the detector:

```c++
template<template<class ...> class Op, typename ...Args>
struct Detector<void_t<  Op<Args...>>, Op, Args...> {
//                       ^^  ^^
//                 has_type  Yes/No
   static constexpr bool value = true;
};
```

For this specialization to match the compiler must make sure that `Op<Args...>`, when replacing the parameters (`Op` and `Args...`) with the actual arguments (`has_type` and `Yes`/`No`), must **name a type** (since that's what the template `void_t` requires as first template argument).

Since `has_type` is not a type, but rather an *alias* of some type, it must look whether whatever is aliased names a type.

For `Yes` this will be `Yes::type`, which again is an alias of `void`. `void` is a type, so everything is fine, the specialization matches, `value` is `true`.

For `No` this will be `No::type`, which does not exist (`No` has no member `type` after all). Thus, the substitution fails (but this is not an error, [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae)), the specialization cannot be used. Thus the compiler chooses the base template, where `value` is `false`.

---

Now what happens when you define `has_type` as follows:

```c++
template<typename T>
struct has_type { using type = typename T::type; }
```

Then above specialization needs (in the `No` case) that a type `has_type<No>` exists. `has_type` is a class template, which given some type (`No` is a type, so everything good) "produces" a type. Thus, `has_type<No>` **is a type**. Thus the specialization matches, `value` is `true`.

**The *members* of `has_type<No>` are not needed at this point.** You could even use `template<typename> struct has_type;` (only a declaration, no definition). In other words, it may be an incomplete type:

> A template argument for a type template parameter must be a type-id, which may name an incomplete type [..]
>
> http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters

The contents only matter when the compiler actually needs them, e.g. for creating an object of that type:

```c++
// Class template with some random members.
template<typename T>
struct Foo {
    using baz = typename T::baz;
    constexpr static int value = T::value * 42;
};

// Class template which is even only declared
template<typename X> struct Bar; // no definition

// Does not use its template parameter in any way. Needs just a type name.
template<typename> struct Defer {};

int main() {
    Defer<Foo<int>> ok;
    Defer<Bar<int>> ok_too;
    // Foo<int> fail;
    // Bar<int> fail_too;
    return 0;
}
```

This mechanism is often used for "type tags", which e.g. can be used to create different types with identical "content" from a single template:

```c++
template<typename /* TAG */, typename ValueType>
struct value_of_strong_type {
  ValueType value;
  // ...
};

struct A_tag; // no definition
using A = value_of_strong_type<A_tag, int>;
struct B_tag; // no definition
using B = value_of_strong_type<B_tag, int>;
```

Both `A` and `B` behave identically, but are not convertible to each other, because they're completely different types.

---

To make the detector work with such class templates as you showed you need  the following specialization:

```c++
template<template<class ...> class Op, typename ...Args>
struct Detector<void_t<typename Op<Args...>::type>, Op, Args...> {
//                     ^^^^^^^^            ^^^^^^
   static constexpr bool value = true;
};
```

Though you cannot just add it, otherwise you run into ambiguous resolution errors.