# why is this short snippet of template code valid?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

As per the title, I do not understand how can the following code compile when `has_type_struct<no_type>` is certainly an invalid type.

```
template<typename T>
using my_int = int;

struct no_type {};

template<typename T>
struct has_type_struct { using type = typename T::type; };

template<typename T>
using has_type_using = typename T::type;

int main() {
   my_int<has_type_struct<no_type>> a; // why does this compile?
   //my_int<has_type_using<no_type>>(); // this rightfully does not compile
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program is valid because `has_type_struct<no_type>` is not instantiated.

[[temp.inst]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#1):

> Unless a class template specialization has been explicitly instantiated or explicitly specialized, the class template specialization is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires a completely-defined object type or when the completeness of the class type affects the semantics of the program.

The use of `my_int<has_type_struct<no_type>>` does not require `has_type_struct<no_type>` to be complete, therefore the latter is not instantiated and the validity of the dependent name in its definition is not checked.

Comment: I think it's very surprising that the validity of the template argument is never checked in this case, but it looks like it's a direct consequence of that snippet of standardese.

Comment: p.s. w.r.t. the standard, one might argue that in this case the "completeness of the class type" *does* affect the "semantics of the program", but oh well

Comment: Completeness of a type means something specific, see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type#Incomplete_type). Completeness doesn't affect semantics in your case. For another example, we can forward-declare a class template to use as a template argument: `template <typename> class fwd; my_int<fwd<short>> b;` The type of `b` wouldn't change if we provide a definition for `fwd`.